# Whatever happened to the "Tan" theme in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, themes, visual-studio-2022

I can't find it anywhere (for 2022)!  Was I the only person on Earth who liked it?

Comment: If you mean [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AnnaOwens.tanThemeVS), then it's an extension but only works for VS-2019.

Comment: @AdrianMole yeah, that's the one.  I'm using 2022.  I should've said that...